# Debugging in VSCode with XDebug prevents website from loading when adding breakpoints

Tags: php, xdebug, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When running XDebug w/ VSCode and setting a breakpoint the site hangs at a certain point after debugging all the way through. Additionally, if I put a breakpoint on a page that isn't even hit it will still fail. If I do not set a breakpoint everything is fine. Below is my configs:

XDebug configurations in php.ini

```
 [XDebug] 
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1 
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

launch.json

```
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9000,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/mnt/c/": "c:/"
    }
}
```

Comment: @RolandStarke This is correct, I did not describe well enough. Just updated my post. Basically the site hangs if I continue all the way through or if there is a breakpoint set on a page that isn't even ran.

Comment: Collect Xdebug log for such failed session and see what it has to say about it -- it may give some hints. Or maybe whole xdebug/php process is crashing etc -- maybe check other (system) logs for that .. or try different xdebug version.